# Downloading 3gp Video from Youtube Rtsp URL on Android

Tags: android, ios, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to download the 3gp video file from Youtube's rtsp URL and save it to my external storage, but it appears that the method I have only works with HTTP URL.

I received this warning:

```
09-02 10:32:40.877: WARN/System.err(7988): java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: rtsp
```

My download method is the following:

```
public static void downloadFromURL(String url, File cacheDir, String fileName) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String TAG = "DL";
        if (url != null) {
            if (fileName.contains("/"))
                fileName = fileName.replace("/", "-");
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            URL mUrl = new URL(url);

            URLConnection ucon = mUrl.openConnection();

            ucon.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
            ucon.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

            File f = new File(cacheDir, fileName);
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];


            int len;
            while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
            }
            // clean up
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            inStream.close();

            android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Download completed in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
        }
    }
```

FYI I test it on my Nexus 7 with Wi-Fi connection.
Let me know if anybody has the solution to the problem I'm having.

**UPDATE**

Anyway, I found these Objective-C snippets which do the request I need, but I'm clueless to turn it into Java codes:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=7ubt8AWa7SU"; //7ubt8AWa7SU gylfmQgtMJc
    NSURL *infoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSString *info = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:infoUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (info == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
        return;
    }
    NSArray *urlComponents = [info componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSArray *itemComponents;
    NSString *urlEncodedFmtStreamMap = NULL;
    for (NSString *item in urlComponents)
    {
        itemComponents = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        if (itemComponents)
        {
            NSString *first = [itemComponents objectAtIndex:0];
            if ([first isEqualToString: @"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"])
            {
                urlEncodedFmtStreamMap = [itemComponents objectAtIndex:1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    NSString *type = NULL;
    NSString *urlSeg1 = NULL;
    NSString *sig = NULL;
    if (urlEncodedFmtStreamMap)
    {
        NSArray *formats = [[urlEncodedFmtStreamMap stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        for (NSString *item in formats)
        {
            type = NULL;
            urlSeg1 = NULL;
            sig = NULL;
            NSArray *pairs = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
            for (NSString *pair in pairs)
            {
                NSArray *varComps = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
                NSString *varName = [varComps objectAtIndex: 0];
                NSString *varValue = [[varComps objectAtIndex: 1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                if ([varName isEqualToString: @"type"])
                {
                    NSArray *typeSegments = [varValue componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];
                    type = [typeSegments objectAtIndex:0];
                }
                else if ([varName isEqualToString: @"url"])
                {
                    urlSeg1 = [varValue stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                }
                else if ([varName isEqualToString: @"sig"])
                {
                    sig = varValue;
                }
            }
            if ([type isEqualToString:@"video/mp4"] && urlSeg1 && sig)
            {
                self.videoUrl = [[urlSeg1 stringByAppendingString: @"&signature="] stringByAppendingString: sig];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, I know this is off topic in terms of programming but check 5B of  http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms

Comment: Are you working on emulator ?

Comment: @66CLSjY well, according to wikipedia 'to download means to receive data to a local system from a remote system'. Just 'Watching' a youtube video would be considered a download too. Is it only a download when you open your web browser and click on text that says 'download'?

Comment: You might be better either just using the download helper extension in firefox or alternatively controlling the download helper extension in firefox as some kind of BHO. All the hard work has already been done, I'd look to build a wrapper rather than reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way of doing it. Getting an RTSP stream is not as simple as a HTTP GET request. The video and audio data packets are sent as RTP, essentially UDP packets with extra data, and then you have RTSP and RTCP (which you can ignore) for server/client communication.

I would recommend looking into the MediaPlayer and Stagefright source code, especially where they set up different data sources and see if you can extract parts of the RTSP handshaking and the setup of the RTP session.